# How can I separate every other or every 3rd string from a stream of strings coming in via COM PORT in real time?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, split, serial-port

I have a stream of strings coming in via serial Port continuously at a fixed baud rate. And I need to separate a specific string every time it is received, split it into useful parts and print those parts in Winform interface. Any help and/or example is appreciated

I am receiving GPS data and have connected it to PC via UART to serial port. Setting up serial port with WinForms and receiving data is no problem. Placing filters to synthesize required messages and handling them is what I need help for.

```
   ////////////// This code is only for reference to the GUI ////////////
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.IO;
  using System.IO.Ports;


   namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
        public Form1()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
          }
            private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
        }
        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();   
         }
        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
        private void Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
         string data = serialPort1.ReadExisting(); //reads the whole 
                                             readbuffer

            if (data.Length >= 10)
               {
                    richTextBox1.Text = data;
                   }   
              }
                  private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
                serialPort1.Close();
               }
           } 
         }
```

For Example: If you see the GPS data in the image

```
(link: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fidyl.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F05%2Fraw-gps-data-8.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fidyl.io%2Farduino%2Fhow-to%2Finterface-gps-module-arduino%2F&docid=zNdHsCmZc93QIM&tbnid=P0_E1tvN1Ur0HM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjh9NudvqTgAhVL4eAKHYtyDHYQMwhbKA0wDQ..i&w=597&h=496&bih=938&biw=1920&q=gps%20data&ved=0ahUKEwjh9NudvqTgAhVL4eAKHYtyDHYQMwhbKA0wDQ&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=496&imgdii=P0_E1tvN1Ur0HM:&vet=10ahUKEwjh9NudvqTgAhVL4eAKHYtyDHYQMwhbKA0wDQ..i&w=597)
```

you will see that different messages are coming in cyclic order. I am interested in every message that starts with "$GPGGA". I want to read only this message every time it occurs, split it into useful parts, print them, and then go back to receive the next message that starts with "$GPGGA".

Note: When reception is not good, gps skips the positions in message that are reserved for actual readings so the string size gets smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a regular expression, or by splitting the received string using '$' - since each line starts with this character.

```
// Holds the partial/unprocessed data we've read from the serial port.
private string _serialRxString = string.Empty;

private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  serialRxString = string.Empty;
  serialPort1.Open();
}

private void Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Add the new data to what we have.
  _serialRxString += serialPort1.ReadExisting();

  // Each line starts with a '$'.
  string[] lines = _serialRxString.Split(
    new char[] { '$' },
    StringSplitOptions.None);

  // Don't process the last one yet, it might not be complete.
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
  {
    // Check if it's the line we're looking for.
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("GPGGA"))
    {
      string[] values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });

      // Do what you want with the values from the $GPGGA line.

    }
  }

  // Keep the last line, since it might not be complete yet.
  _serialRxString = lines.Last();
}
```

You also might want to subscribe to the serial port data received event.  This way any data received on the serial port will automatically be processed, without having to click the read button.  You can do this either through the designer or in your form constructor.  Then the data received event would be the same as what's in the `Read_Click` function above.

To subscribe to the `DataReceived` event in the designer:

[image: Subscribing in the designer]

Or in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
}
```

The data received event then would be:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(
  object sender,
  SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  // Add the new data to what we have.
  _serialRxString += serialPort1.ReadExisting();

  // Each line starts with a '$'.
  string[] lines = _serialRxString.Split(
    new char[] { '$' },
    StringSplitOptions.None);

  // Don't process the last one yet, it might not be complete.
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
  {
    // Check if it's the line we're looking for.
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("GPGGA"))
    {
      string[] values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });

      // Do what you want with the values from the $GPGGA line.

    }
  }

  // Keep the last line, since it might not be complete yet.
  _serialRxString = lines.Last();
}
```

Then whenever anything is received on the serial port this function automatically gets called.

There are also some packages available for parsing NMEA messages that might be helpful.  Such as this one: [NmeaParser](https://github.com/dotMorten/NmeaParser)

Comment: Please elaborate on subscribing to serial port data receiving event.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this question comes up a lot.  You've already done the hard part, that is sending/receiving data.  Now you just need to parse it.  Looks like from the example image, everything is comma delimited and each line ends with a Carriage Return Line Feed.  See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991963/2009197), you should be able to build a string for each line then split it on commas and get the field you are looking for.