# How to extract very specific parts out of a string in C# and use them in winform application?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split, serial-port

I have data coming in via serial port. Currently, I am receiving it and splitting it at every "," (see the code for reference). Right now, I am using (for each) function which makes substring @ every comma encountered. But I don't want this.

What I need is, lets say, to extract only ALPHA, BRAVO, and CHARLIE out of String1 and if data is missing like shown in String2, my extraction should also result in empty substring(s).

The problem is that this data is from a GPS device and if signal strength is not good, the string comes in empty i.e. only commas. So, string length can change either slightly or heavily(String1 represents complete string while String2 represents string with omissions).

String1: $GPBWC,220516,ALPHA,00046.34,BRAVO,T,CHARLIE,0004.6,N,EGLM*11

String2: $GPBWC,,,0,BRAVO,,,,N,EGLM*11

I understand that some relevant questions have been asked previously but I am unable to find a solution that is robust enough. So, any and all help is appreciated.

**Code:**

```
private string serialRx = string.Empty;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    serialRx += serialPort1.ReadExisting();                                              
    string[] lines = serialRx.Split(new char[] { '$' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.None);        

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)                                          
    {
        if (lines[i].StartsWith("GPGSV"))                                                
        {
            string[] values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });                       

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() => displaySplits(value)));
            }                   

            Invoke(new Action(() => displayReceivedText(lines[i])));           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ALPHA, BRAVO and CHARLIE? If you have a specific string, then you know it and don't have to extract it. Do you need something that comes after/before those strings? Or maybe you mean the specific input e.g. third for ALPHA and fifth for BRAVO etc. ?

Comment: Are the strings terminated by a Carriage Return (CR) or a Line Feed (LF)?  If so, you can build a string until you have the whole line and then parse your line.  See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991963/2009197

Comment: Based on this library [dotMorten/NmeaParser](https://github.com/dotMorten/NmeaParser), you can add your necessary items. [BWC | NMEA data](https://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#BWC)

Comment: @PatiK Alpha, Bravo and Charlie represent values that I need. They are location based and change continuously. In case of good signal strength, no. of characters is constant but the values change continuously and in case of bad reception, nothing is received i.e. there will be no data in these slots.

Comment: @Ahmed I probably don't understand something, because it seems too easy for me. From what I gathered, you always get the same number of data separated by coma (sometimes there are only comas, but comas always appear in the same number). Why don't you just use _values[2]_ dla ALPHA, _values[4]_ for BRAVO and _values[6]_ for CHARLIE? They will return what you want: either the value or empty string. If a line can be shorter just check its length and then use the indexer.